# Using 'and', 'or' with 'be torn between"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the following sentence correct?

> "I'm torn between choosing the white color font **and** black one."

What about this one?

> "I'm torn between choosing the white color font **or** black one."

Should I use only "and" between two options? Or maybe "or" as well?

Comment: What makes you think it might *not* be "correct"?

Comment: Most people would omit **choosing** (which is implied) and **color** (which is redundant). Simply: *I'm torn between the white font and the black one.*

Comment: Please add more detail about why you are interested in this idiom, and why you think your usage might be right or wrong?  Otherwise the question may be closed as *proofreading*.

Comment: You could be torn **over** choosing white or black, but I'd agree with Ronald Sole, you are torn **between** white and black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be correct:

"I'm torn between the white color font and the black one."

You don't need to use "choosing".